# Show image and then change link using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

Hours of searching and still no answer I can understand for this one: I am trying to add a link whose href changes depending upon which image in a carousel is selected (i.e. pick an image and then the link at the bottom changes).

Pick the currrent image by changing the opacity of a the current image display using the class opaque-fabric:

```
        $('#current').ready(function() {
                        $("#carousel-2 img").click(function() {
                            $("#current img").removeClass("opaque-fabric");

                            var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
                            $("#current #"+imageToShow).addClass("opaque-fabric");

                            $("#carousel-2 img").removeClass("selected-fabric");
                            $(this).addClass("selected-fabric");            
                        });

                    });
```

Then change the end of the href in the "choose-button" anchor link of my page:

```
    $('.choose-button').ready(function() {
                            $("#carousel-2 img").click(function() {

                var button = $(this).attr('class');
                var currenthref = $(".choose-button").attr('href');
                $(".choose-button").attr('href', currenthref + button);


            });

        });
```

The image display part works, but I cannot seem to append the href in the button. Please help and speak slowly (beginner).

**EDIT**: [Here's what I'm working with](http://www.cutlerycart.com/bed-selector), on a test server.

Comment: can you post some HTML & CSS code, please?

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to really understand your question but you have a few serious errors. First you're not using `ready()` correctly. From jQ API:

> *The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document.*

Then you should be using `attr()` instead of `prop()` since `href` is an attribute, not a property.
Also `live()` is deprecated in favor of `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .append() function is used to append DOM elements to other DOM elements. If you want to update the href property, use the syntax

```
var currenthref = $(".choose-button").prop('href');
$(".choose-button").prop('href', currenthref + button);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did as you said and made sure to define the button variable as well and still I can't get the button's href to change-- it just stays the same. Thanks, though. I'll try editing the question with an example.